# add blobs or trees to a created repository using pygit2 (libgit2)?

Tags: python, git, libgit2

I am trying to use pygit2 library.

seems I got stuck on the first step. its documentation doesn't explain how to create a blob and add it to a tree. It is mostly around how to work with an existing git repository but I want to create one and add blobs, commits, ... to my repo. Is it possible to create a blob from a file directly or should I read the file contents and set blob.data?

```
from pygit2 import Repository
from pygit2 import init_repository

bare = False
repo = init_repository('test', bare)
```

How can I create and add blobs or trees to the repository?

Answer (score 7):

The python bindings don't let you create a blob from a file directly, so you'll have to read in the file to memory and use `Repository.write(pygit2.GIT_OBJ_BLOB, filecontents)` to create the blob.

You can then create trees with the `TreeBuilder`, for example, like

```
import pygit2 as g

repo = g.Repository('.')
# grab the file from wherever and store in 'contents'
oid = repo.write(g.GIT_OBJ_BLOB, contents)
bld = repo.TreeBuilder()
# attributes is whether it's a file or dir, 100644, 100755 or 040000
bld.insert('file.txt', oid, attributes)
treeoid = bld.write()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, how can I learn more about pygit2? none of what you mentioned is in pygit2 document, How did you learn how to use it?

Comment: @PeqiHash Carlos is one of the developers of libgit2

Comment: If you changed a file do you still add the whole file to the repo as a blob and then reference that oid with an insert using TreeBuilder...or is there something to do with a patch here?

Comment: Patches exist on a different level. The full contents of each version of a file are contained in a blob. If you update it, you need to update the blob and any tree leading from it up to the root.

Comment: How to handle it if the file may be inside a subdirectory (and the directory may or may not exist yet)? It seems that I cannot write `bld.insert('path/to/file.txt', oid, attributes)`.

Comment: For that you'd use an `Index` which is made to do such operations. The 0.25 release of libgit2 will have a function to update trees given arbitrary-depth paths.